# Ambient isotopy taking a polygon knot to another polygon knot

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Let me define that a polygon knot means a knot K of which all point belongs to some line segment which is a subset of K.

Let me ask if knot theory has some proof for that:

For all pair ( K1, K2 ) of polygon knots which are R3 ambient isotopic to each other,

some R^3 ambient isotopy H exists such that H takes K1 to K2 and all H( K1, t ) is a polygon knot for all time point t of H.

And if it does, could you give me how to prove it?

If there is some unlear point in my question, let me explain it.

Comment: Sorry, you're asking if any two knots are isotopic?

Comment: @Mike Miller, No. I am very sorry, it was not what I had meant at all. Please check the corrected question.

Comment: OK. In that case, yes, it's true (indeed you can assume that H is a PL map for all t; that's how I'd prove the statement), though I don't know a good reference.

Comment: I think Reidemeister's original proof of his thereom is done using polygonal knots.